# How to get child views of listview item from outside the adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I want to thank you in advance for the solution to my question.

I have a custom adapter for my listview. the list item has an imageView(1), a progressBar(3), and a download button(2).

[image: listitem]

When the download button for each list item is clicked, I grab vital details of the listitem such as the position of the view,  the resourceid of the button, the resource id of imageview and the resource id of progress bar, then i make an parcealable object of class "Download".

```
Download download = new Download();
download.setUrl(url);
download.setButtonResource(this.downloadBt.getId());
download.setCreativeWork(creativeWork);
download.setDownloadBt(this.downloadBt);

download.setProgressBarResource(this.progressBar.getId());
download.setProgressBar(this.progressBar);
download.setContext(activity);
download.setViewResource(view.getId());

Intent intent = new Intent(activity, BroadcastService.class);
intent.putExtra("download", download);

Log.e("download button", url);

activity.startService(intent);
```

I start a service which does the download and reports back using a broadcast. When this broadcast message is received I want to update the progress bar.

My problem is how to get the progress bar concerned from my mainactivity which receives the message. How do I reference this?

I am currently using a parcelable object to pass the resource id for the progressbar, all the way from the adapter to the service, then to the receiving activity(mainActivity) using the intent's putExtra(), then I do this at the mainActivity

```
Download download = (Download)intent.getParcelableExtra("download");
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(download.getProgressBarResource());`
```

The issue here is that always only returns the first item of the list, regardless of which listitem is clicked. I would want to get each unique listitem and update the progress bar and the download button. Thanks

Comment: you need pass position along with the broadcastReceiver method so that you can get it when progress is udated. and then update value at that List of position

Comment: @RahulKhurana no, position of the clicked item can change (because other downloads can be finished in the meantime for example), what should be passed is a unique ID that never changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you show this layout in a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. First thing that need to do is, add a field for `index` in your `Download` class to identify the position in the list from where that button was pressed. Next, pass the `index` from your `getView()` or `onBindViewHolder()` to the function that creates the `Download` object and add that `index` to the object.

When you receive the when you broadcast any update from your `Service`, do include the `index` value. Now, in your code in your activity where you receive the broadcast value, extract the value of `index` and the `progress`. Now, you could write something like this to update the progress of that view in the list:

```
int index = ... //some value you received in broadcast
int progress = ...//some value you received in broadcast

View view = listView.getChildAt(index);
if (view != null) {
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}
```

Comment: @KennethNgedo glad to hear that. Please mark the answer correct and upvote it so that others can also reference this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the solution to your problem

1. First You need to pass progress value to the adapter that may be zero in start.
2. Implement `setOnItemClickListener` for your listview

   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   ```
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               final int position, long id) {
          //now point to your item position and do your stuff here
       }
   });
   ```
3. When ever you receive broadcast for download progress. Just update your ListView by Nullifying previous items with new items containing download progress values.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you looking for...

In you adapter.  do below..  (I take a sample from my project which do a delete card from the list, when the delete button is clicked)

In getView function inside adapter.

```
Card card = list.get(position);
viewHolder.imgDelete.setTag(card);// --> i set the whole card info to tag
```

outside the adapter.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.iv_delete_card) {

            //System.out.println("---> Card: " + tag);

            //delete card 
            Object tag = v.getTag();
            if (tag != null && tag instanceof Card) {
                promptDeleteCard((Card) tag);
            }

        }
    }
```